# Issues on consuming a WebService from another WebService

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis, rampart

I developed an axis2 webservice, and then this client with a tool from Eclipse WTP.
After that, i engaged rampart, and everthing goes fine.

Now I'm developing an application that uses the client, so i've dropped that client in another tomcat, but now seems that client and server won't communicate anymore.

error from the client:

```
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: The server did not recognise the action which it received: 
org.apache.axis2.handlers.addressing.AddressingInFaultHandler.invoke(AddressingInFaultHandler.java:114)
org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invoke(Phase.java:318)
org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.invoke(AxisEngine.java:251)
```

from the server:

```
[WARN] triggerActionNotSupportedFault: messageContext: [MessageContext:
    logID=urn:uuid:DE6B0886AE07B55CA41320863048370] problemAction: urn:RequestList
    [ERROR] The [action] cannot be processed at the receiver.
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: The [action] cannot be processed at the receiver.
    at org.apache.axis2.addressing.AddressingFaultsHelper.triggerAddressingFault(AddressingFaultsHelper.java:373)
```

The problem seems to be the settings of `services.xml`.. but I configured it properly and the `option.setAction("urn:RequestList")` instruction appears in the code.